# Identifier Enum is Undefined

Tags: c

Ok i see this is a fairly common problem, but i cannot find a question that is similar to my problem.

I keep getting problems with

```
identifier "Baserate" is undefined
```

I am defining this as

tim.h

```
#include "tim_api.h"
enum Baserate {
 Rate_62_5ns = 0x0,
 Rate_125ns = 0x1,  
 Rate_250ns = 0x2,  
 Rate_500ns = 0x3, 
 Rate_1us = 0x4,    
 Rate_2us = 0x5,    
 Rate_4us = 0x6,    
 Rate_8us = 0x7,    
 Rate_16us = 0x8
};
```

the problem is when i define the function it is used in

tim_api.h

```
extern void TIM_Set_Period_ns(int Timer_Select, Baserate Set_Baserate, int Period);
```

this is when i am building an embedded c program but when i run this in a c consol app  it works

```
void TIM_Enable(Baserate my_baserate, void (*callback_function)());
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
TIM_Enable(Rate_62_5ns,prnt0);  
while(1);
return 0;
}


void TIM_Enable(Baserate my_baserate,void (*callback_function)())
{
}
```

So my question is why does the same enum Baserate work in the console app but not in the embedded program.

Comment: tim.h *includes* tim_api.h *before* `Baserate` is defined, but tim_api.h *uses* `Baserate`.  Is the code you have posted real?  You have a circular dependency and no *[include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C you need to use `typedef enum Baserate {/*your values here as before*/} Baserate;`

That is one of the subtle differences between C and C++.

Comment: aah gotcha, this worked, thank you very much. is there a reason this was changed in c++

Comment: I suspect that not doing so would have made using `class`es very tedious.

Comment: If C++ didn't behave this way then you'd have to write `class MyClass an_object = new class MyClass();` everywhere.

Comment: @Chrusciki:  Because in C++ they took the opportunity to clean up all the thinks about C that rare truly annoying and unnecessary. It is not a problem, the C typedef idiom works in C++ also, so it is forward compatible.  A simpler solution may have been to use C++ compilation and enjoy all the other benefits.

Answer (score 3):

Without a `typedef` you need to declare a `Baserate` as follows

```
enum Baserate {
    Rate_62_5ns = 0x0,
    Rate_125ns = 0x1,  
    Rate_250ns = 0x2,  
    Rate_500ns = 0x3, 
    Rate_1us = 0x4,    
    Rate_2us = 0x5,    
    Rate_4us = 0x6,    
    Rate_8us = 0x7,    
    Rate_16us = 0x8
};

enum Baserate a_rate = 0x6;
```

With a `typedef`

```
typedef enum {
    Rate_62_5ns = 0x0,
    Rate_125ns = 0x1,  
    Rate_250ns = 0x2,  
    Rate_500ns = 0x3, 
    Rate_1us = 0x4,    
    Rate_2us = 0x5,    
    Rate_4us = 0x6,    
    Rate_8us = 0x7,    
    Rate_16us = 0x8
} Baserate;

Baserate a_rate = 0x06;
```